# Setting limits on number of iterations of a for loop in C#

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

I have the following `for` loop in C#;

```
for (int i = 0; i < oDTEvent.Rows.Count; i++ )
{
    EventAlerts += DataUtils.GetStringField(oDTEvent.Rows[i], "DateTime") + " " + DataUtils.GetStringField(oDTEvent.Rows[i], "Description") + " \n";
}
```

I want to limit the number of iterations to a maximum of 10.

I cannot do the following:

```
for(int i=0; i<10;i++)
```

as there will not always be 10 rows in the table.

I have tried:

```
int i=0;
while (i < 10)
{
    for (i = 0; i < oDTEvent.Rows.Count; i++ )
    {
        EventAlerts += DataUtils.GetStringField(oDTEvent.Rows[i], "DateTime") + " " + DataUtils.GetStringField(oDTEvent.Rows[i], "Description") + " \n";
    }
}
```

but this does not work as the inner `i` will not increment the outer `i`

I have also tried

```
int i=0;

for (i = 0; i < oDTEvent.Rows.Count; i++ )
{
    while (i < 10)
    {
        EventAlerts += DataUtils.GetStringField(oDTEvent.Rows[i], "DateTime") + " " + DataUtils.GetStringField(oDTEvent.Rows[i], "Description") + " \n";
    }
}
```

but doesnt work either

Comment: add: "If (i > 9) break;" as the first instruction in the loop

Answer (score 13):

You can add more than one condition on the loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < oDTEvent.Rows.Count && i < 10; i++ )
{
    EventAlerts += DataUtils.GetStringField(oDTEvent.Rows[i], "DateTime") + " " +          DataUtils.GetStringField(oDTEvent.Rows[i], "Description") + " \n";
}
```

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch45axte.aspx) of `for` (emphasis mine):

> The condition section contains a **boolean expression** that’s evaluated to determine whether the loop should exit or should run again

Answer (score 3):

The problem that you are having is that you aren't breaking the inner loop when it hits 10.

The while loop you have with the for loop inside of it will execute forever.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < oDTEvent.Rows.Count; i++ )
    {
        //If the counter has incremented past 9 then break the loop
        if(i > 9)
          break;

        EventAlerts += DataUtils.GetStringField(oDTEvent.Rows[i], "DateTime") + " " +  
                   DataUtils.GetStringField(oDTEvent.Rows[i], "Description") + " \n";

    }
```

Comment: This answer is slightly better than @petelids because it allows you to add code to the IF(i>=10) statement.This way, you can distinguish between exiting the loop on either condition.

Comment: @steenbergh - I agree if that's the intent but the OP doesn't suggest they need to distiguish between the two.

Comment: I have to agree that @petelids answer is better. It really comes down to who's consuming it. In the case of the student who is clearly confused on basic coding fundamentals I prefer the most verbose answer which I think mine is. For production code though, clearly his answer is much better.

Comment: @petelids true, and I upvoted both. But given no specifics, this one is the most flexible at no significant increase in overhead.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to loop at most 10 times, or the number of rows:

```
for (int i=0; i < Math.Min(oDTEvent.Rows.Count, 10); i++) { ... }
```

This just takes the smaller of the two numbers.

Answer (score 2):

try,

```
int max = oDTEvent.Rows.Count > 10 ? 10 : oDTEvent.Rows.Count;

for (int i = 0; i < max; i++ )
{
     EventAlerts += DataUtils.GetStringField(oDTEvent.Rows[i], "DateTime") + " " + DataUtils.GetStringField(oDTEvent.Rows[i], "Description") + " \n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < oDTEvent.Rows.Count; i++ )
{
    if(i >= 10) {
        break;
    }
    EventAlerts += DataUtils.GetStringField(oDTEvent.Rows[i], "DateTime") + " " +          DataUtils.GetStringField(oDTEvent.Rows[i], "Description") + " \n";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(10, oDTEvent.Rows.Count); i++ )
{
    EventAlerts += DataUtils.GetStringField(oDTEvent.Rows[i], "DateTime") + " " +          DataUtils.GetStringField(oDTEvent.Rows[i], "Description") + " \n";
}
```

Comment: Won't math.min get executed on each iteration?

Comment: yes, up to 10 times :)  i'll take that trivial hit in exchange for readability

Comment: won't the compiler optimize this and cache the min value? I usually do this outside the loop but I'm curious.

Answer (score 1):

Before Your for loop do this:

```
int loopLimiter = 0;
if (oDTEvent.Rows.Count >= 10)
{
  loopLimiter = 10;
}
else
{
  loopLimiter = oDTEvent.Rows.Count;
}
```

Or to make it cleaner:

```
oDTEvent.Rows.Count >= 10 ? loopLimiter = 10 : loopLimiter = oDTEvent.Rows.Count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int i=0;
int maxInt = 10;

    for (i = 0; i < oDTEvent.Rows.Count; i++ )
    {
        if (i >= maxInt)
            break;

        EventAlerts += DataUtils.GetStringField(oDTEvent.Rows[i], "DateTime") + " " + DataUtils.GetStringField(oDTEvent.Rows[i], "Description") + " \n";


    }
```